# Is it possible to track JSONP calls to my site, via Google Analytics?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsonp

Since it's a lightweight JSONP callback to my site, I don't think there is a way to get standard Google Analytics tracking, unless I'm mistaken?

Otherwise I'll have to track on my own, inside my action (asp.net MVC 2 site), correct?

What sort of tracking would you do here?

Answer (score 1):

what about using event tracking?

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure that's even possible. The action returns only a json object. It looks like server side is the only way here.

Comment: how are you calling your jsonp? if there's a success function you can tack along to it, you can trigger an event from there just by calling _trackEvent

Comment: Oh... is that something that would be ok to do from another person's site?

Comment: oh. hah. I read it backwards. I assumed YOU are making the calls, not serving the call. can you put the tracking call in the script that serves the json? a hack would be to do a GET request to a resource that executes the track call. but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I probably could get it added into the script, not sure if it would count hits on the other site though. Would it start tallying all the hits the other sites get and add it into my tracking or is there a way to have it do nothing but let me use the event tracking?

Comment: well if there's any caching going on their end, there's nothing you can do, I think. but otherwise, it'll count the number of times the script gets run